# Pyspark - calculate average velocity in group based on time and location

Tags: group-by, pyspark

I have the following PYSPARK dataframe:

```
+-------------------+----+---------+------+
|      timestamplast|ship|  X_pos  |time_d|
+-------------------+----+---------+------+
|2019-08-01 00:00:00|   1|     3   |   0  |
|2019-08-01 00:00:09|   1|     4   |   9  |
|2019-08-01 00:00:20|   1|     5   |  11  |
|2019-08-01 00:00:27|   1|     9   |   7  |
|2019-08-01 00:00:38|   2|     3   |   0  |
|2019-08-01 00:00:39|   2|     8   |   1  |
|2019-08-01 00:00:57|   2|     20  |  18  |
+-------------------+----+---------+------+
```

Where timestamplast is the datetime, time_d is the time difference within group "ship" (time_d is zero when a new "ship" starts. I want to calculate the average velocity within group "ship" and append the result to the dataframe based on the time difference and the position X_pos

The average velocity for ship==1 would be :(1/9 + 1/11 + 4/7)/3 = 0.26 m/s.
The average velocity for ship==2 would be :(5/1 + 12/18 /2 = 2.83 m/s.

EDIT:
The average velocity for ship==1 would be :((4-3)/(9) + (5-4)/(11) + (9-5)/(7))/3 = 0.26 m/s.
The average velocity for ship==2 would be :((8-3)/1 + ((20-8)/18)) /2 = 2.83 m/s.

Results should look like:

```
+-------------------+----+---------+------+-----------+
|      timestamplast|name|     X   |time_d| avg_vel_x |
+-------------------+----+---------+------+-----------|
|2019-08-01 00:00:00|   1|     3   |   0  |     0.26  |
|2019-08-01 00:00:09|   1|     4   |   9  |     0.26  |
|2019-08-01 00:00:20|   1|     5   |  11  |     0.26  |
|2019-08-01 00:00:27|   1|     9   |   7  |     0.26  |
|2019-08-01 00:00:38|   2|     3   |   0  |     2.83  |
|2019-08-01 00:00:39|   2|     8   |   1  |     2.83  |
|2019-08-01 00:00:57|   2|     20  |  18  |     2.83  |
+-------------------+----+---------+------+-----------|
```

Comment: can you explain the calculation part a bit?

Comment: My bad, in Pandas it would be:  `df['vel_x'] = ((df.groupby("name")['X'].diff().fillna(0)) /(df['time_d']).replace([np.inf,-1*np.inf],0)).fillna(0)`. And then:
`df['avg_vel'] = df.groupby(['name'])['vel_x'].transform('mean')`

Comment: for ship == 2 your output sum isnt correct.. can you check?

Comment: why do you divide ship 1 by 3 and ship 2 by 2 in the end? Also please do not edit the question any further as it wastes everybody's time

Comment: Ship 1 has four records and ship two has 3 records. I calculate the average velocity for the whole group "ship", so divide the sum by the length of the records . Because of `((df.groupby("name")['X'].diff().fillna(0))` gives a zero on the first index, I dont think it into account in the average.

Comment: Well, `((4-3)/(9) + (5-4)/(11) + (9-5)/(7))/3` is `0.26` not `0.77` ...right?

Comment: Indeed you are right ... it has been a long day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transform` in pandas can be replicated by windows function in pyspark similar to sql , your expected output for `ship` == 1 should be `0.26` instead. You can try:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy('ship')
pct_change=((F.col("X_pos")-F.lag("X_pos").over(w.orderBy("timestamplast")))
                                                /F.col("time_d"))
df.withColumn("avg_vel_x",F.round(F.sum(pct_change).over(w)
                                 /(F.count("ship").over(w)-1),2)).show()
```

---

```
+-------------------+----+-----+------+---------+
|      timestamplast|ship|X_pos|time_d|avg_vel_x|
+-------------------+----+-----+------+---------+
|2019-08-01 00:00:00|   1|    3|     0|     0.26|
|2019-08-01 00:00:09|   1|    4|     9|     0.26|
|2019-08-01 00:00:20|   1|    5|    11|     0.26|
|2019-08-01 00:00:27|   1|    9|     7|     0.26|
|2019-08-01 00:00:38|   2|    3|     0|     2.83|
|2019-08-01 00:00:39|   2|    8|     1|     2.83|
|2019-08-01 00:00:57|   2|   20|    18|     2.83|
+-------------------+----+-----+------+---------+
```